# Java not compiling .class files under $CLASSPATH

Tags: java, class, package, javac

I'm trying to figure out how organize source and class files working with packages. I found a very useful [tutorial](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/java/package/managingfiles.html). But I still have some questions.

As far as I understood it is a good practice to have an isomorphism between name of packages and name of the directories where elements of a package are stored. For example if I have a package named `aaa.bbb.ccc` which contains class `ddd` it is a good practice to have a class file called "ddd.class" and located in "$CLASSPATH/aaa/bbb/ccc/". Did I get it right?

If it is the case, will Java compiler put *.class files into the correct directory automatically?

I was not able to get this behavior. I set the `$CLASSPATH` variable to  `"/home/myname/java/classes"`. I executed `javac KeyEventDemo.java` which contains `package events;`. I expected that javac will create a subdirectory `events` under `/home/myname/java/classes` and put the `KeyEventDemo.class` in this subdirectory.

It did not happen. I tried to help to javac and created "events" subdirectory by myself. I used `javac` again but it does not want to put class files under "/home/myname/java/classes/events". What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use the `-d` option to specify where you want the `.class` files to end up. Just specify the base directory; `javac` will create any directories necessary to correspond to the right package.

Example (based on your question):

```
javac -d ~/java/classes KeyEventDemo.java
```

Comment: And to clarify $CLASSPATH: it will tell the JVM where to look for classes during runtime, not to tell javac where to create classes this answer and your experience show.

Answer (score 4):

> For example if I have a package named
>   "aaa.bbb.ccc" which contains class
>   "ddd" it is a good practice to have a
>   class file called "ddd.class" and
>   located in "$CLASSPATH/aaa/bbb/ccc/".
>   Did I get it right?

That's not "good practice" - this is how the Sun JDK *expects* things to be. Otherwise, it will not work. Theoretically, other Java implementations could work differently, but I don't know any that do.

> If it is the case, will Java compiler
>   put *.class file into a correct
>   directory automatically?

Yes

> What am I doing wrong?

The source code must *also* already follow this structure, i.e. KeyEventDemo.java must reside in a subdirectory named "events". Then you do "javac events/KeyEventDemo.java", and it should work.

Comment: If you use the `-d` option (highly recommended, so binaries live in a different place from the source), then in theory, your source does not have to follow that hierarchy.

Comment: On the java.sun.com I found out that it can be convenient to keep *java and *class files in different directories. And I would like to use this approach.

Comment: As Chris wrote, you can use the -d option for this. But it's still a very good idea to keep the source files in the same directory hierarchy, or it will be very confusing.

Answer (score 2):

It is not only good practice but a **must** in most cases.

consider a Java class named:

```
com.example.Hello
```

If you store it on the filesystem, it has to got to

```
/path/to/my/classes/com/example/Hello.java
```

The compiler (or at least the vast majority) will create the class file at

```
/path/to/my/classes/com/example/Hello.class
```

Personally I would not use the `CLASSPATH` variable to set the path but the `-cp` option on java. A call to the above "application" could be done with:

```
java -cp /path/to/my/classes com.example.Hello
```